# How to Verify (VerifyTests) a private member of a class

Tags: c#, mstest, verify-tests

I want to Verify a class, but it does not have any public members.  Here is the class:

```
public class SpreadsheetValuesList
{
    private readonly List<SpreadsheetValue> _spreadsheetValues = new();

    public SpreadsheetValuesList(string json)
    {
        _spreadsheetValues = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<SpreadsheetValue>>(json ?? "[]", new JsonSerializerOptions());
    }

    public void Add(SpreadsheetValue spreadsheetValue)
    {
        _spreadsheetValues.Add(spreadsheetValue);
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(_spreadsheetValues);
    }   
}
```

When I call verify on this object in a MSTest, I get this:

[image]

The Verify documentation does not seem to have anything about this, nor Stack Overflow.
So I tried a few things:

1. I (naively) made an override `ToString` method thinking that maybe Verify would call it and put it in the **Test.received.txt** file.  It did not.
2. I searched the [github repo](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify) thinking maybe there is an attribute I can use, but no.
3. I tried [TreatAsString](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/blob/main/docs/serializer-settings.md#treatasstring), but this does not work either.  If you read the fine print in the doc it says when the object is passed "directly" to verify.  I am not doing that.  I am only verifying it as a component of another object.
4. If I expose the List as a public property `public List<SpreadsheetValue> Values { get; } = new();` then it appears in the received.txt file like this:

[image]

This is what I want, but I do not want to break the encapsulation of my class just so I can get a test to work.  Is there a way to provide a method or attribute on a public method so Verify can output the data to the received/verified file?

This class is used as a component of other classes, so I am calling Verify on the larger class like this:

```
// Assert
await Verify(viewModel);
```

Comment: Now after asking the question, I am just thinking to myself.  Jeez, why don't I just write a simple Assert statement.  But I do have this class used in several Verify tests.  It would be nice to solve this problem so it can "just work" for all of my use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do not write unit tests for private members or methods. Instead, write tests for the public-facing behavior of your class. Some ideas that fit the philosophy of unit testing:

1. Write unit tests for the `ToJson()` method. This might require some code gymnastics to format the expected JSON in code, but remove unnecessary formatting when comparing your expected output to the actual output.
2. Expose a public `IEnumerable<SpreadsheetValue>` property:

   ```
   public IEnumerable<SpreadsheetValue> Items => _spreadsheetValues;
   ```
3. Since your `SpreadsheetValuesList` is logically a list, this class can implement `IEnumerable<SpreadsheetValue>` directly:

   ```
   public class SpreadsheetValuesList : IEnumerable<SpreadsheetValue>
   {
       private readonly List<SpreadsheetValue> _spreadsheetValues = new();

       public SpreadsheetValuesList(string json)
       {
           _spreadsheetValues = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<SpreadsheetValue>>(json ?? "[]", new JsonSerializerOptions());
       }

       // Add() and ToJson() methods omitted for brevity

       #region IEnumerable<T> interface

       System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       {
           return this.GetEnumerator();
       }

       IEnumerator<SpreadsheetValue> GetEnumerator()
       {
           return _spreadsheetValues.GetEnumerator();
       }

       #endregion
   }
   ```

The nice thing about option 3 is you have a functionally complete class that you can use in a `foreach` loop, or use with LINQ queries:

```
var values = new SpreadsheetValuesList("some JSON");

foreach (var value in values)
{
    // do something with value
}
```

This makes asserting the internals feel a little more idiomatic for C#:

```
var values = new SpreadsheetValuesList("some JSON");

Assert.AreEqual(2, values.Count());
Assert.AreEqual("Baz", values.First().Foo);
```

Don't be afraid to add additional readonly properties for other intersting internal information, like the total number of items:

```
public int Count => _spreadsheetValues.Count;
```

The main thing is to never expose the data in your class in a way that allows the outside world to mutate that data unpredictably. This keeps your tests (and code) deterministic.

Read [How do you unit test private methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/100959/118878) for an interesting SoftwareEngineering.SE post about this same subject.

Comment: Awesome ideas!  I do have direct tests for this class.